# Flex TextInput width 100%

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

How can I set the Flex TextInput component to have 100% width, so that it has width fill up the parent width space? I tried with `<s:TextInput id="myid" width="100%"/>` but didn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: It should. Probably something with the layout of the parent container. You should provide a little more context.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to bind to parent width by using

```
<s:TextInput id="myid" width="{width}"/>
```

In such situations I usually set different background colors to component so I can see where the problem is. 
In flex 3 I do it just with setting backgroundColor property, in flex 4 I use rectangle:

```
<s:Rect height="{height}"
        width="{width}"
        includeInLayout="false">
        <s:fill>
             <s:SolidColor color="{Math.random() * 0xffffff}"/>
        </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
```

If you still have a problem, maybe post your parent code.

Comment: Whenever I see Flex 4 (Spark) code like this which requires 4-7 lines of mxml for what used to be a single attribute, I'm glad that my employer makes upgrading so absurdly difficult...

Comment: Yes background color style ( as many others ) are removed from most of containers ( if you want it you can you BorderContainer ). Scrollbars are also removed, layout logic was incapsulated to different classes. 
And it's good! As containers are much lighter now, I can feel the difference. 
The same about Rect. It's not a child of UIComponent so it's light.  Also all graphic elements which you have in one class will be drawn on  graphic layer of one ( parent ) component. And it's also good from performance point of view.

Comment: Well, I can't deny performance here. But I do wish we hadn't taken a major step back in the API's ease of use in the process.

Comment: Using such things as Rect class gives more flexibility, for example drawing gradients without as code. 
But yes, it true that in ideal case both options should be possible. I've migrated big project from flex 3 to 4 just few months ago and styling was the most painful part.

Comment: I wonder if it'd be difficult for the Apache team to add some simple attributes like this to Spark? I imagine the way it'd function would be as simple as a setter with code which does essentially what you have above here (minus the random()). I don't think it'd effect performance... seems easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

`<s:TextInput id="myid" width="{myid.text.length * 2}"/>` You can dynamically increasing the size of Text Box..

Answer (score 0):

What you posted is correct.  Most likely something is causing the TextInput's parent container to be smaller than you think.  Try setting some explicit width(s) on the container(s) along with either visible borders or background colors so you can see what's going on. It's hard to just guess without any context.